# How to create dynamically variable for setInterval?

Tags: javascript, variables, setinterval

I create a hmtl page with node and ejs with an unforseeable number of elements. I would like to create a setInterval for some, none or all of those elements, depending what the user is doing.

The problem is, that I am not able to create a dynamically variable for the setInterval so that I can later on cancel those Intervals.

Maybe I just need another simpler approach but at the moment I am stuck here.

```
camContainer.forEach(element => {
        clearInterval(intervalVar);
        if (!element.classList.contains("hidden")) {
            countVisible++;
            intervalVar = setInterval(showConsole, 1500);
        } else {
            countHidden ++;
        }
    count++;    
    })
```

I tried it with an Array instead of a regular variable but that didnt work either

```
intervalVar[count] = setInterval(showConsole, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with an array, but you need to push items onto it:

```
intervalVar = []

// ...

intervalVar.push(setInterval(showConsole, 1500))
```

When you want to cancel an interval, remove it from the array with `slice` or `pop`, depending on how you're selecting the item to cancel.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works.

I run into the next problem that now all intervals dont run in a specific order. I then created just one interval and put all needed values into one array with "var.push()" and processed it in the setInterval. So you brought me right on track! :-)